# Weka: Results of each fold in 10-fold CV

Tags: machine-learning, weka

For Weka Explorer (GUI), when we do a 10-fold CV for any given *ARFF* file, then what Weka Explorer provides (as far as I can see) is the average result for all the 10 folds.

**Q.** Is there any way to get the results of each fold? For instance, I need the error rates (incorrectly identified instances) for each fold.

Help appreciated.

Comment: why dont you use weka API instead? It will allow you much finer control.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this *is* possible using Weka's GUI. You need to use the Experimenter though instead of the Explorer. Here are the steps:

1. Open the `Experimenter` from the GUI Chooser

   - Create a new experiment (`New` button @ top-right)
   - [optional] Enter a filename and location in the `Results Destination` to save the results  to
   - Set the `Number of (cross-validation) folds` to your liking (start experimenting with 2 folds for easy results)
   - Add your dataset (if your dataset needs preprocessing then you should do this in the Explorer first and then save the preprocessed dataset)
   - Set the `Number of repetitions` (I recommend 1 to start of with)
   - Add the algorithm(s) you want to test (again start easy, start with one algorithm)
2. Go to the `Run` tab and `Start` the experiment and wait till it finishes
3. Go to the `Analyse` tab and import the experiment results by clicking `Experiment` (top-right)

   - For `Row` select: `Fold`
   - For `Column` select: `Percent_incorrect` or `Number_incorrect` (or any other measure you want to see)
   - You now see the specified results for each fold

Comment: Great! It indeed worked perfectly! Thank you! I still have a few questions- (1) what does the value in iteration control indicate? (2) What do the options datasets first/ algorithm first mean? (3) In the analyze tab how can I run a significance test? I am sorry if I am overwhelming with questions here. =)

Comment: Good to hear that it works. The `Number of repetitions` simply performs the experiment several times allowing for more stable results (10 repetitions and 10 cross-validation folds thus means 100 runs). You can see results of each repetition by selecting `Run` in `Row`/`Column`. The `data/algo first` choice can be useful if you want all algorithms to run first on each dataset or vice versa (run all datasets over the 1st algorithm, then the 2nd algo, etc). The significance test is simply run by loading a finished experiment and then clicking `Perform test`. More info here: http://is.gd/5CWmfv

Answer (score 4):

Weka Explorer does not have an option to give the results for individual folds when using the crossvalidation option, there are some workarounds. If you explicitly don't want to change any code, you need to do some manual fiddling, but I think this gives more or less what you want

1. Instead of `Cross-validation`, select `Percentage split` and set it to 90%
2. Start classifier
3. Click `More options...` and change the `Random seed for XVal / % Split` value to something you haven't used before.
4. Repeat ten times.

This is not exactly equivalent to 10-fold crossvalidation though, since the pseudo-folds you make this way might overlap.

An alternative that is equivalent to crossvalidation, but more cumbersome, would be to make 10 folds manually by using the unsupervised instance filter `RemoveFolds` or `RemoveRange`.
Generate and save 10 training sets and 10 test sets. Then for every fold, load the training set, select `Supplied test set` in the classify tab, and select the appropriate test fold.