# Results from each fold in 10-fold Cross Validation in WEKA, using command-line.

Tags: java, macos, machine-learning, classification, weka

This question is similar to this one: [Weka: Results of each fold in 10-fold CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860264/weka-results-of-each-fold-in-10-fold-cv) but I am instead looking to get the same results from the command-line.

Hence, if this is my input

```
java -cp "./weka.jar" weka.classifiers.trees.J48 -t ./WEKA_reference_test_set.arff -x 10 -i > test.csv
```

How can I specify my output so that I can see the results for each fold? Thanks.