# Cross validation: folds results in weka software

Tags: machine-learning, weka, cross-validation

I'm wondering if there is a way to see the reults of the "k" folds in WEKA software.

My meaning is - if I have 10 folds cross validation, the final result will be the confustion matrix's average of the 10 folds.
Could I pull the answer of each fold separately?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A similar question is answered in [Weka: Results of each fold in 10-fold CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860264/weka-results-of-each-fold-in-10-fold-cv?rq=1). But I think it's better to use weka API, so you need to split the dataset by yourself and then use train/test mode for each segmentation. You can search the weka manual to find the functions provided.