# How to get each folds' results in 10-fold cross-validation

Tags: java, weka, cross-validation

Actually, I know there is a GUI method to get each fold's results in 10-fold cross-validation in weka, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860264/weka-results-of-each-fold-in-10-fold-cv), but I am programming using weka api.

Unfortunately, My results [`My results`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3od1S.png) from java program are quite different from the results in weka's explore [`GUI results`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSgHp.png). My code is partenter image description hereially given below,

```
Instances data1 = DataSource.read("D:/Users/.../XX.arff"); // upload the dataset
data1.setClassIndex(data1.numAttributes()-1); // set class index
data1.randomize(new Random(1))
data1.stratify(10); // stratify the dataset into 10 folds
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    Instances train = data1.trainCV(10, i);
    Instances test = data1.testCV(10, i);
    RandomForest rf = new RandomForest();
    rf.buildClassifier(train);  
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
    eval.evaluateModel(rf, test);
    ... // then I compute each folds' results using eval.XXX()
}
```

The results calculated by the above codes of 10-fold cross-validation is different from that obtained the standard weka GUI, I don't know which part of my code is wrong? Can anyone meet the same problem as me?

Comment: I suppose that *WEKA* might not take the mean value of results in 10 folds as the final results, My 10 precision in each folds are `0.333 0.556 0.625 0.667 0.714 0.750 0.833 0.833 0.833 1.000` ,but the results in 10-fold cross validation are `0.707`. Oh ~~

Comment: each evaluation in the for loop is unique as the variables are freshly assigned. you're actually getting what you want.

Comment: That's why I instantiate a new `Evaluation` object eval in each for-loop, but I can't get what I want :( . I am going crazy ...

Comment: can you describe what is precision(in) and precision(out) ?

Comment: Hi, @ShaurabhBharti, `in` and `out` are 2 classes in my classification, so the `precision(in)` is the precision in `in` class while `precision(out)` is the precision in `out` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, after wasting so much time in exploring the reason why the average of 10 folds' results are mismatched with the results of final 10-fold cross-validation in WEKA, I finally find the 3 points，

> 1) My Java code is right, which means that *randomize()*, *stratify()*, *trainCV()*, and *testCV()* are used correctly.
>
> 2) The results of 10-fold cross-validation in WEKA are Not equal the mean of the results of each fold.
>
> 3) The results of 10-fold cross-validation in WEKA are calculated by confusion matrix.

For the third point, for example, in each fold, WEKA will get `precision`, `recall`, `f-measure`, `AUC`, `ROC`, `errorRate` such measures as well as a confusion matrix, which defined as cm(i). Then, the final results of 10-fold cross validation also can get a confusion matrix CM, which defined as,

```
CM = cm(1) + cm(2) + ... cm(10)
```

Finally, the `precision`, `recall`, `f-measure`, `AUC`, `ROC` such measures are calculated by this confusion matrix CM, which really supraise me a lot @^@.