# Incosistency of results in ten-fold cross validation in WEKA

Tags: weka, cross-validation

Yesterday, I use 2 ways to implement the 10-fold cross validation in weka, but the results are inconsistent.

Way 1: directly invoke method `eval.crossValidateModel()`,

```
 J48 j48 = new J48();
 j48.buildClassifier(ins);  // ins is the Instances object
 Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(ins);
 eval.crossValidateModel(j48, ins, 10, new Random(1)); // 10-fold cross validation
 ... // get results by eval.getXX(0) or eval.getXXX(1)
```

Way 2: using method `testCV()` and `trainCV()` in each fold,

```
 ins.randomize(new Random(1)); // ins is the Instances object
 ins.stratify(10); // randomize the dataset then split into 10 folds

 for(int i=0; i<10; i++){       
    Instances trainData = ins.trainCV(10, i);
    Instances testData = ins.testCV(10, i);
    J48 j48 = new J48();
    j48.buildClassifier(trainData);

    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
    eval.evaluateModel(j48, testData);
    ... // get results by eval.getXX(0) or eval.getXXX(1)
 }
```

According to the weka api docs, the above 2 ways should have the same results, i.e., the average results(e.g., precision, recall) of way 2 should be equal to the results of way 1. But the truth is that they are not the same, can anybody figure out the bug in my code, or provide other nice evaluation methods? Thank you all!

Comment: I also noticed that there are some GUI solutions to obtain the results in each folds [Weka: Results of each fold in 10-fold CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860264/weka-results-of-each-fold-in-10-fold-cv), the results also are inconsistent with that one which uses `crossValidateModel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the code of the `weka.classifiers.Evaluation.crossValidateModel` method (depending on your version, the delegate object), you will see that it uses the `weka.core.Instances.trainCV(int,int,Random)` method. Furthermore, you need to initialize the `Evaluation` object with the class priors of the complete dataset.

Here's the updated code:

```
Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(ins);  // init evaluation
rand = new Random(1);
int numFolds = 10;  // 10-fold CV
ins.randomize(rand); // randomize the data
ins.stratify(numFolds); // stratify the randomized data for 10-fold CV
J48 template = new J48();  // classifier template for evaluation
//template.setOptions(...);  // if further options need to be set

for (int i = 0; i < numFolds; i++) {       
  Instances trainData = ins.trainCV(numFolds, i, rand);
  Instances testData = ins.testCV(numFolds, i);
  Classifier cls = AbstractClassifier.makeCopy(template);  // copy of classifier template
  cls.buildClassifier(trainData);
  eval.evaluateModel(cls, testData);  // accumulate statistics
}

... // get results by eval.getXX(0) or eval.getXXX(1)
```

Comment: Yeah, The source code of `crossValidateModel()` does use the random seed in calling `trainCV(int,int,Random)`, but I tried to use the `trainCV(int,int,Random)`, but the results are also beyond the results from **Way 1**. Another question is that we need to initialize the `Evaluation` object with `trainData` rather than `ins`.

Comment: According to my trials, the results of **WAY 1** and **WAY 2** are consistent with the results obtained by using Weka GUI in **Explorer** and **Experimenter** modules, respectively. I noticed that there are so many related questions post on Weka forum, is this a bug in Weka?

Comment: Experimenter and Explorer handle cross-validation differently. The Explorer combines the results of one cross-validation run in a single Evaluation object (like the command-line). The Experimenter treats each fold-pair as a separate evaluation. This is why the Experimenter can calculate mean/stdev and the Explorer can't.

Comment: I think your right, but the official usage example doesn't use the random seed in `trainCV()` method in each fold, see [CrossValidationSingleRun.java](https://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/CrossValidationSingleRun.java/82916749/CrossValidationSingleRun.java). Another question, why you use `makecopy()` method instead of instantiate a `J48` object?

Comment: That's an old example that I wrote many years ago (when I was more involved with the Weka project). Things have changed in between. We're currently in the process of moving the wiki anyway. Will update it the code there. The `makeCopy` method is used so you only ever have to configure the classifier once. For instance, if you perform cross-validation to obtain statistics and then afterwards build a final model on the full dataset for deployment. Each time simply creating a copy of your template using the `makeCopy` method (and you only have to change the settings in a single place).

Answer (score 1):

**Way1** is the basic method that are widely-used in Weka GUI, so `crossValidationModel()` can give the same average results with the *Weka Explorer*, like the following operations.

1.Open **Weka** softweare

2.Enter <kbd>Explorer</kbd> module

3.Choose dataset in <kbd>Preprocess</kbd> tab

4.Choose *J48* and *10-fold* cross-validation in <kbd>Classify</kbd> tab

5.Click <kbd>start</kbd> button to obtain results in **Classifier output** window

**Way2** is an alternative method that we can get results of each folds. The results of each folds are the same with the that in *Weka Experimenter*, like the following operations.

1. Open **Weka** software
2. Enter <kbd>Experimenter</kbd> module
3. Click <kbd>New</kbd> button to new a *simple* experiment in <kbd>Setup tab</kbd>
4. Set parameters in **Results Destination**, **Datasets**, and **Algorithms**
5. Click <kbd>Start</kbd> button in Run tab, the results of each fold are saved in the file defined in **Results Destination**

All in all, These 2 methods definitely return the 2 difference results, according to the source code given be its office website https://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+cross-validation+folds+(Java+approach), the above methods should obtain consistent results, but the truth is the exact opposite, maybe this is a bug of Weka.